# Minimising redirect chain in .htaccess setup

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https, http-status-code-301

I'm at a basic level of understanding when it comes to `.htaccess` redirects but I'm managing to just about get by with a site I'm redeveloping. I have searched Stack Overflow quite extensively, but can't understand how to put together all the advice in the context of my own situation.

I'm switching my WordPress the site to `https` and so far have managed to cobble together the following set-up:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have a few bugs I'd like to iron out though, currently `http://` redirects to `https://` which then redirects to `https://www`.

How do I set up an additional rule to move everything from `http://` directly to `https://www`. ?

Also there are some pages I'd like to redirect to new URLs in the `https` site. `http://www.example.com/bunny` to `https://www.example.com/rabbit`. How is the best way (least 301 chains) to redirect these from insecure to a new secure URL?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to replace your redirect rules to this (*adapt your domain*):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on`
You need to something like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and in wp-admin:

```
wordpress site Address Url : https://Your_site_url
Site Address Url:https://Your_Site_Url
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've implemened your suggestions but I'm now getting a too many redirects error and the site is crashing?

Comment: Have you removed ?
`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Comment: Yes in its entirety the file now reads `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# END WordPress`

Comment: you need to use edited .htaccess. I have edited ans.

Comment: Thank you, I've uploaded it exactly as instructed but changed the domain. I can confirm site URLs are correct in wp-admin as well but I'm still getting the redirect error. Any suggestions appreciated :)